# Typescript Generics constraint not working

Tags: typescript

Hi guys so I have this problem

I'm creating a service that i only want to use with a constraint

for that I have an interface

```
abstract class Base {

}


class ModelFromBase extends Base {

}

interface IService<T extends Base> { 
   doSomething(model: T); 
}
```

and this class that implements the interface

```
class ModelNotFromBase {

}

class Services<ModelNotFromBase>  implements IService<ModelNotFromBase> {
       doSomething(model: T) {} 
}
```

The issue is that ModelNotFromBase does not extends Base (as name suggests), and the TS compiler does not scream about it.

Also when I'm creating an IService instance

```
private _instance: IService<ModelNotFromBase>;
```

same issue, I mean i could provide anything there.

So what is the issue here,

As the documentation shows you can use constraints

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Is there something that I'm missing out ? or am I not doing it the correct way ?

Comment: You sample doe not compile,`ITemplatingService` is `IService` ? `ModelNotFromBase` is used as a type parameter for `Services`, is it also a class ? could you post the code for `Base` and `ModelNotFromBase` ?

Comment: ah sorry, I will fix this right now .. yes ITemplatingService is IService. So I have Base which is just a marker and the interface should only work with models extending Base ex ModelFromBase .. but as you can see , i have ModelNotFromBase which can be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how `Base` and `ModelNotFromBase` are defined, this may be the expected behavior. When determining type compatibility, typescript uses structural compatibility. This means that these two classes are perfectly compatible with one another:

```
class Base {
    name: string;
}

class ModelNotFromBase {
    name: string;
}
var b : Base = new ModelNotFromBase(); // Works fine
```

If the class/interface `Base` is empty (`class Base { }`), then the constraint, does not really constrain anything as any other type can be assign a variable of this type

```
class Base { }
var d : Base = 0;
var d2: Base = "";
```

If you want to avoid structural typing, you can define a private property on the `Base` class (it does not have to be used it just has to be present) and then constraint can only be satisfied by a class that inherits `Base`:

```
class Base { 
    private nonstructural: true;
}
class ModelNotFromBase { }

interface ITemplatingService<T extends Base> {
    doSomething(model: T);
}

export class Services<T extends Base> implements ITemplatingService<T> {
    doSomething(model: T) { }
}

var  _instance: ITemplatingService<ModelNotFromBase>; //error 
export class OtherServices implements ITemplatingService<ModelNotFromBase> { // also error
    doSomething(model: ModelNotFromBase) { }
}
```

Comment: @MCR edited the answer, I meant for the `nonstructural` field to be private